# if we have a while loop inside while loop, do we multiply complexities? (even though pointers are used)

Tags: python, time-complexity

Here is some code that takes a list of integers, nums, and a target integer, target, and returns the two integers in nums that adds up to target:

```
def twoSum(nums, target):
    pointer_stat = 0
    pointer_run = 1

    while pointer_stat < len(nums):

        while pointer_run and pointer_stat < len(nums):
            if nums[pointer_stat] + nums[pointer_run] == target:
                return [nums[pointer_run],nums[pointer_stat]]

            pointer_run +=1

        pointer_run = 1
        pointer_stat +=1


print(twoSum(nums,target))
```

My question is, or rather I wanted to confirm if the above is O(n^2) runtime?

My reasoning is that we have two pointers that will point to each of the integers in the list, and both pointers will traverse the list once each (thus O(N) complexity), and since we have a loop within a loop, we multiply O(N) and O(N) to get O(N^2)

And space complexity is O(1).

Comment: There are no pointers. Yes, you multiply the complexity

Comment: I'm really unclear on why you think setting an integer counter is a pointer, and how that has any baring on runtime complexity for nested loops

Comment: Nested loops don't always mean quadratic complexity. It depends on the problem. Are you touching each input number only once? Then it's linear. Are you touching all input number once for every other input number? then it's quadratic. '

Comment: I don't get it @rdas. If you have nested loops and you only use values once then... actually I'm totally confused. The nested iteration still has to happen and check _something_ even if it's an O(1) set lookup

Comment: @rdas we are touching each input number once with each of the two 'pointers', so both pointers in the worst case would iterate over all of the input once time

Comment: @roganjosh If you have only one index in your nested loops and you stop all the loops when the index reaches the end of the array, then you can have any number of nested loops and your time complexity would still be linear.

Comment: @rdas thanks. I think my brain is hard-wired to look at the other end of the spectrum vs. reducing it down like this, but that is logical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right but O(n^2) is *worst-case* time complexity as you include a return statement in your loop that can cause to exit the double-loop earlier.

Please note that you might want

```
while pointer_run < len(nums) and pointer_stat < len(nums):
```

instead of

```
while pointer_run and pointer_stat < len(nums):
```

as this can cause to not stop your loop (less than binds stronger than "and") and run indefinitely.

Comment: Hi Vgar, I did know that it is the worst case, which is what Big O records correct? - I do see your point about the loop potentially breaking earlier if the condition is met.

Comment: Big O notation describes the behavior of (growing) functions in a simplified manner. We still can differentiate between best, avg and worst case (each with Big O): this helps to e.g. distinguish two linear telephone book search algorithms. Example: Alg. 1 stops after it found the entry, Alg. 2 searches through the whole book every time. Now, let's search the entry "A" (best case). We can see that the best case performance of Alg. 1 is O(1) (immediate hit) and Alg. 2 is O(n). Your algorithm relates to the latter one so you can determine a best, avg and worst case performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually test it and see it for yourself:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=[]
y=[]
n=[1]
def twoSum(nums, target):
    pointer_stat = 0
    pointer_run = 1
    iterations = 0

    while pointer_stat < len(nums):

        while pointer_run < len(nums) and pointer_stat < len(nums):
            if nums[pointer_stat] + nums[pointer_run] == target:
                return [nums[pointer_run],nums[pointer_stat]]
            iterations +=1 
            pointer_run +=1

        pointer_run = 1
        pointer_stat +=1
        x.append(len(nums))
        y.append(iterations)
    return True

for i in range(100):
    n.append(1)
    twoSum(n,10000)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xlabel('N')
plt.ylabel('Iterations')
plt.show()
```

[image]